# DAX measure not working properly when I add date conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got 2 measures to obtain dates.

```
Start Month 2 = EOMONTH(MAX(Treatments[Treatment Date]), -2) + 1 + time(0,0,1)
```

and

```
End Month 2 = EOMONTH([End Month 1], -1) + time(23,59,59)
```

and for example, if I select 21/06/2023 on my slicer, I should get the following
Start Month 2 = 01/05/2023 00:00:01 and End Month 2 = 31/05/2023.

Then I've got the following measure

```
Test 2 (Manual) = 
(COUNTROWS(FILTER('Treatments',
'Treatments'[Treatment Status] = "Completed" &&
Treatments[Treatment Date] <= [End Month 2]  &&
Treatments [Treatment Date] >= [Start Month 2])))
```

and the result of Test 2 (Manual) is 13610 which is incorrect, it should be 2652, I don't know why the date conditions are not working on my DAX measure. I have already changed the settings on the card to ignore the slicer dates so it doesn't affect my result, but it is still giving me an incorrect results for some reason. Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score -2):

There seems to be an issue with your **`DAX` measure**, which is **resulting in an incorrect count**. Here's how you can try:

```
Test 2 (Manual) = 
(COUNTROWS(
    FILTER('Treatments',
        'Treatments'[Treatment Status] = "Completed" &&
        Treatments[Treatment Date] <= [End Month 2]  &&
        Treatments[Treatment Date] >= [Start Month 2]
    )
))
```

Check the **'Treatment Status'** condition:

- Ensure that the **"Completed"** status is correctly assigned to completed treatments.

Verify the values of `[Start Month 2]` and `[End Month 2]`:

- Check the values of `[Start Month 2]` and `[End Month 2]` to ensure they are correctly calculated based on the selected date from the slicer.

Check the date conditions:

- **Confirm** that the date conditions in the `FILTER` function are correctly comparing the **'Treatment Date'** column with the calculated start and end dates.

**To test you can modify your measure as follows to isolate the date conditions:**

```
Test 2 (Manual) - Date Range Only = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER('Treatments',
        Treatments[Treatment Date] <= [End Month 2]  &&
        Treatments[Treatment Date] >= [Start Month 2]
    )
)
```